# Socket.io : what happen to the client(socket) after a user is disconnected? Can I/Should I remove it?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io, and I want to know how can I remove the client(socket) after a connection is closed. (In fact, I don't know what is going on after a connection is close, will that socket remained there? Should I remove it? Will it take up memory?)

```
My code:

socket.No = socketNo++;
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Server calling update collection with socket No.",socket.No);
    },3000);

    //When connection is close()
    socket.on("disconnect",function(){
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
})
```

What happen is that, for example, I disconnect from the server, I find that server is still logging. What can I do so that I can stop it?

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above, it is `setInterval` that is causing the additional logging.

You will need to store off the id returned from `setInterval` then clear it using `clearInterval` on a disconnect event.

Something like:

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Server calling update collection with socket No.",socket.No);
    },3000);

    //When connection is close()
    socket.on("disconnect",function(){
        console.log("A user disconnected");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
})
```

Other than that, no need to do anything else with the socket on the server side.  It will get garbage collected at some point.